# libsndfile Emscripten environment

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten, libsndfile, emcmake

I am running just a little code using libsndfile, in the [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) environment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sndfile.h>

int main() 
{
    SF_INFO info;
    const char * path = "~/data/somefile.wav";
    SNDFILE* sf = sf_open(path,SFM_READ, &info);
    if(sf == NULL) 
    {
        std::cout<< sf_strerror(sf) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout<<info.samplerate<<std::endl;
    
    std::cout<<"Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

So ideally if I run this with normal `cmake` (Apple Clang compiler) everything works fine, the `samplerate` and `hello world` are printed, but when I run this with `emcmake cmake` (em++ compiler) and run the compiled `node main.js` file it says `System error: no such file or directory`. Who can help me with this? Who has experienced such thing?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

The problem is that [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#using-files) has its virtual file environment. So if you want this file to be uploaded and later be *seen* in compiled `.js` file, you need to add compile flag `--preload-file <FILE_PATH>` , after that the **file with given path** will be recognized by emscripten environment.